# Jquery UI Problem with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, autocomplete

How do you get a list of all projects from a model such as Project.all and all the project.name's in there moved to a listed in javascript which is then printed out using Jquery UI Autocomplete

[Link to Jquery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote)

```
$( " #tags " ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response){
            //pass request to server
            $.ajax({
                url: "/projects/project_list",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    term: request.term
                },
            minLength: 1,
            select: function( event , ui ) {
                                            log( ui.item ?
                                            ui.item.value : +  this.value );
                                            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you are probably looking for something like this:

```
 def project_list  
   list=Project.all.map{|i|[i.name,i.id]}
  arr= [["No project",0]].concat(list.sort{|a,b| a[0]<=>b[0]}).to_json
  render :json =>arr
 end
```

You then need to call this method from inside the js

```
     $("#some_input_id").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            //pass request to server
            $.ajax({
                url: "/projects/project_list",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
#do stuff here
}
});
});
```

Here's a relatively complete example of some that produces an autocomplete list of airports

```
   $("#airport, #station").autocomplete({
        delay: 1000,
        search: function(event,ui){
            tag = event.target.id
        },
        source: function(request, response){
            //pass request to server
            $.ajax({
                url: "/tags/"+ tag +"/list",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        if (tag == "airport"){
                            return {
                                label: item.airport.fd_name
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return {
                                label: item.station.fd_name
                            }

                        }

                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        open:   function( event, ui ) {
            stripe($(this));
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
```

And here's the associated controller code:

```
def list
    @tags= params[:tagclass].titleize.constantize.where("fd_name ilike ? ",params[:term]+"%").order('fd_name')
    render :json =>  @tags.to_json(:only=>[:fd_code, :fd_name]), :layout=>false
  end
```

`

Comment: at the moment the javascript is looking at var availableTags = [projects, here]

Comment: project_list outputs an array here -updated it so it outputs json.  There are lots of ways to do this - I don't have a nice simple example in my code and am cutting and pasting and tidying bits to try and clarify but may be causing confusion ...

Comment: is there suppose to be an { at the end of the JS im getting an error

Comment: yes - the code is not complete - the success function will need to do something with the data returned from the server ...

Comment: `$( " #tags " ).autocomplete({
   source: function(request, response){
        //pass request to server
        $.ajax({
             url: "/projects/project_list",
             dataType: "json",
             data: {
                  style: "full",
                  maxRows: 12,
                  term: request.term
               },

   minLength: 1,
   select: function( event , ui ) {
    log( ui.item ?
     ui.item.value :
      +  this.value );
   }
  });`

Comment: @AhmetAbdi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1846/discussion-between-chrispanda-and-ahmet-abdi)